# remove black background of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've been adding a swipe to dismiss on the root ViewController of a UINavigationController, and it works, but as you're panning the view, there is a black background behind it. The UINavigationController is presented modally over another view, and I'd like to display the view that's underneath as the user pans, but I can't find a way to change the black background or where it is set on the UINavigationController. Does anyone know how I can change this?

Thanks...

Comment: Could you share a screenshot, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working just by changing

```
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
```

to

```
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
```